# Startup Application open terminal and run command

Tags: pantheon-terminal, startup, ssh

I want to create a custom command in startup applications that will open a terminal and run a command. The command is an alias for connecting to an ssh server.

Alias

```
schat
```

Command

```
ssh elem@10.10.0.2 -p 2022
```

I tried using the following as a custom command for a startup application, but I just get a blank terminal window with no output and no way to input anything.

```
io.elementary.terminal --execute=schat
```

Comment: I ended up just install gnome-terminal and am going to be using it as my default terminal from now on. The new startup command is: gnome-terminal -- ssh elem@10.10.0.2 -p 2022

Answer (score 0):

Try it without telling the Terminal to execute a command in Terminal.

[image: custom command]